# Relationship between Opportunity, OpportunityLineItems(Opportunity Product), PricebookEntry, Product2 & Pricebookentry in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, soql, community, relationships, standard-objects

Correct me if am wrong in these relation Ship between Opportunity, OpportunityLineItems(Opportunity Product), PricebookEntry, Product2 & Pricebookentry in Salesforce.

1. OpportunitylineItem is junction object between opportunity and pricebookentry.
   As We need PricebookEntry Id and opportunity Id while creating OpportunityLineItems.
2. PricebookEntry is a junction object between Product2 and PriceBook.
   As we need Product2 Id and PriceBook2 Id while creating PricebookEntries.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both points are correct, see here ERD: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_products.htm

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fred, Thanks Ratan for clearing the doubt, its correct as per doc as well :)

Answer (score 4):

*Opportunity Product  is a Junction Object between Opportunity and Product2 objects. The API name is OpportunityLineItem.*

The relationship between Product2 and PriceBookEntry is 1:M(Master Detail) with PriceBookEntry on the child side.

The relationship between PriceBook2 and PriceBookEntry is 1:M(Master Detail) with PriceBookEntry on the child side.

**So PriceBookEntry is a Junction object between Product2 and PriceBook2**