# How to hide a single record from Opportunity Product related list in standard salesforce page through trigger?

Tags: trigger

Can we hide a related list's record on parent object as soon as record save to database?  I have requirement whenever Opportunity Product quantity is greater than 100, my trigger code  validate it and make this record alone not visible to end users.

Can any body provide sample  trigger code snippet or ideas to  hide a related record?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not work with the standard Salesforce Opportunity Product as it works like a Master Detail relationship with the Product owned by the Opportunity owner despite being a lookup relationship.

A good definition of Opportunity Products is already [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45706/what-is-the-opportunity-product) and its relationships [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107314/relationship-between-opportunity-opportunitylineitemsopportunity-product-pri)